# excel: formula that returns the same beginning of the text from a column

Tags: microsoft-excel

example below where column B compares column A and returns the same beginning text. note "white" and "white chocolate"

```
Column A                     Column B

Apple Pie                    Apple
Apple Strudel                Apple
Chocolate Cupcake            Chocolate
Chocolate Ice Cream          Chocolate
White                        White
White Chocolate Baclava      White Chocolate
White Chocolate Cheesecake   White Chocolate
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You need to be more explicit.  How many words can there be?  Is it always everything except the last word?  Always the first word unless there's more than two words, then the first two words?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to extract the first word from some text you can use the `FIND` and `LEFT` functions. Taking your example, the formula in B1 looks like this:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)`

How this formula works:

FIND returns the position (as a number) of the first occurrence of a space character in the text. This position, minus one, is fed into the LEFT function as num_chars.

The LEFT function then extracts characters starting at the the left side of the text, up to (position - 1).

Handling one word

If a cell contains only one word, this formula returns an error. One way to fix this problem is to wrap the original formula in the IFERROR function like so:

`=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1),A1)`

Translated: if an error occurs, return the original text.

Another simple way to handle the error is to append a space to the cell value before running FIND:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ")-1)`

This ensures that FIND will always find at least one space, and will therefore not throw an error. When a cell contains more than one word, there is no impact because the formula works only with the first space.